# Access DSL modem web configuration through Wireless Router. .

Tags: wireless-networking, home-networking, adsl

I am having a DSL Modem ZTE 831 Series. To have Wireless Connectivity at home, I have connected Tenda WiFi Router W316R.

The address of DSL Modem is 192.168.1.1 The address of Wifi Router is 192.168.0.1

The physical connection settings are as below:

Modem has only one Lan port e.g before attaching WLAN router i was able to connect only one pc so after purchasing WLAN router, i connected that one Lan port of modem with WLAN router's internet port. So now traffic of modem directed to WiFi Router.

The Wifi Router has 4 Lan Ports and one internet port (connected with modem) and out of 4 remaining LAN ports, 1 of them i am using to connect a PC as i am not having WiFi adapter on that desktop PC.

Other devices are WiFi enabled like laptop and phones etc so i connect them wirelessly.

Now after clearing the scenario, i want to come to the original question that i am want to access DSL modem configuration through browser while being connected to Wifi Router.

I am able to access DSL modem configuration while internet is connected mean when DSL is UP, so I go to 192.168.1.1 through browser and can easily access mode configuration.

But as soon as Internet gets disconnected like when DSL goes down, I can not access modem configuration page.

I am wandering that why it is issue when DSL is down because I am connecting to device on my Local Area.

Can any expert me with that Please.

Comment: Does the modem hang when dsl goes down?or vice versa? If it hangs then no device will be able to access it.

Comment: I can access it if I'm directly connected to modem but can't when indirectly like behind the router.

Answer (score 0):

Your modem and router are on diffirent networks (192.168.1.1 and 192.168.0.1), consider using the router as a switch. If your router does not allow itself being used as a switch then consider upgrading your router firmware to DD-WRT. Check compatibility for your exact model before you do.

Comment: It does not support DD-WRT any other solution by configuration?